# Function to convert a decimal number as a string to hexadecimal

Tags: c++, performance, strings, integer, number-systems

I am designing a cipher and need to convert between bases repeatedly in a loop.  I have optimized everything else, but I'm not too familiar with C++ code, and and am trying to figure out how to make the conversion faster.

```
string digits = "0123456789abcdef";
string tohex(string number) {                        // Decimal to Hexadecimal function
    long length = number.length();
    string result = "";
    vector<long> nibbles;
    for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        nibbles.push_back(digits.find(number[i]));
    }
    long newlen = 0;
    do {
        long value = 0;
        newlen = 0;
        for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            value = (value * 10) + nibbles[i];
            if (value >= 16) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = value / 16;
                value %= 16;
            } else if (newlen > 0) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = 0;
            };
        };
        length = newlen;
        result = digits[value] + result;
    } while (newlen != 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to store text as a string of digits in the first place.

Comment: The cipher reads that as an input.

Comment: It might be worth it to post the whole cipher. This looks like a serious code smell, to me at least.

Comment: Easier to convert it to a number then convert back to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Code Review.

If this is a set of constants you want to chech against then it should by marked as `constexpr`  (or const), that way nobody can actually modify it. Also why pollute the global space with another variable; declare it inside the function (as a static so it only gets initialized once).

```
string digits = "0123456789abcdef";
```

Also there is a standard function to check if a character is a hex digit `std:: isxdigit()`.

Pass objects by reference to prevent a copy.

```
string tohex(string number) {
```

Since you are not modifying `number` make it a const reference.

Note: You should return by value. The optimizer will remove the need to copy out of the function so you don't need to worry about a copy here.

Declare variables as close to the point of usage as possible. Here `result` is declared but not used until the next section of code. So When I start seeing `result` being used I need to scan up the function a long way to find it.

```
    long length = number.length();
    string result = "";
```

This is an interesting way to convert characters into digits.

```
    vector<long> nibbles;
    for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        nibbles.push_back(digits.find(number[i]));
    }
```

But: 1) You don't check for invalid input as a result you may push back `std::string::npos` (a big number that is converted is probably converted to -1 when assigned to long). 2) This is O(n) for every digit. it can be done in O(1).

The standard guarantees that the character-set has all the numbers `0` -> `9` in a contiguous range. So you can convert a character (that is a digit) into a number by subtracting the value of `0` from the character.

```
char d = number[i];
nibbles.push_back((d >= '0' && d <= '9)
                         ? d - '0'
                         : (d >= 'a' && d <= 'f')
                                ? d - 'a' + 10
                                : (d >= 'A' && d <= 'F')
                                     ? d - 'A' + 10
                                     : -1;
```

PS. Don't write that. Put it in a function.

I see what you are doing. But the functionality could be a lot neater.

```
    long newlen = 0;
    do {
        long value = 0;
        newlen = 0;
        for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            value = (value * 10) + nibbles[i];
            if (value >= 16) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = value / 16;
                value %= 16;
            } else if (newlen > 0) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = 0;
            };
        };
        length = newlen;
        result = digits[value] + result;
    } while (newlen != 0);
    return result;
}
```

### This is how I would do it.

How about:

```
template<class T>
string to_string(T t, ios_base & (*f)(ios_base&)) {

  ostringstream oss;
  oss << f << t;
  return oss.str();
}

string tohex(string number) {

    long value = std::stoi(number, null, 10);
    return std::to_string(value, std::hex);
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to use a `to_string` function, and it runs faster.